# Prove that a C2(U) gate (for any single qubit unitary U) can be constructed using at most eight one-qubit gates, and six controlled- NOTs

Tags: quantum-gate, nielsen-and-chuang

Its a Problem from 
Michael Nielsen quantum computation and quantum information