# Is there a way to prove that the number of gates in Exercise 4.22 of Nielsen and Chuang's book is the smallest possible number?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-circuit

I've been going over Nielsen and Chuang's *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* and I ran into Exercise 4.22, which says,

> Prove that a $C^{2}(U)$ gate (for any single qubit unitary $U$) can be constructed using at most eight one-qubit gates, and six controlled-NOTs.

Given $U\in\text{U}(2)$, the operator $C^{2}(U)\in\text{U}(2^{3})$ is a controlled-$U$ gate with two control qubits and one target qubit.
The exercise asks us to construct this purely out of one-qubit gates and CNOTs with the specified number of components.
[The intricate solution to this is given in this post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7082).

This made me wonder a few questions:

- Is there a circuit that *improves* on the number of one-qubit gates or number of CNOTs in any way? To be more specific, is there an equivalent circuit made of only one-qubit gates and CNOTs that has strictly less than $14$ components?
- If the answer is no, is there a *proof* that $14$ components is the least number of components possible for this problem (assuming $U\in\text{U}(2)$ is arbitrary)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the smallest possible number. At least, not without making several additional restrictions.

You can do it in an expected cost of 4.5 two qubit gates and 8 single qubit gates if you use an ancilla, allow feedback, and count arbitrary-basis measurement and arbitrary-basis preparation as single qubit operations.

Here's [the circuit that does it](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%7Esg6%22%2C%22X%5E-%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22X%5Eft%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22t%2F2%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22X%5Eft%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22t%2F2%22%7D%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22X%5Eft%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22-t%2F2%22%7D%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22H%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%7Emila%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%7Esg6%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22X%5Eft%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22-t%22%7D%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%7Emila%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Edk0k%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%7C0%3E%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Evfnf%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%3D%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Em6f2%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%20%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Esg6%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22U%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B0.9816272-0.1019917i%2C-0.1529875-0.0509958i%7D%2C%7B0.1529875-0.0509958i%2C0.9816272%2B0.1019917i%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Emila%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22U%5E-1%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B0.9816272%2B0.1019917i%2C0.1529875%2B0.0509958i%7D%2C%7B-0.1529875%2B0.0509958i%2C0.9816272-0.1019917i%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D):

[image]

Note that I'm assuming all adjacent single qubit operations are fused together, and that includes the classically controlled X being conditionally fused with the final $U^{-1}$.

Note that I'm not counting classical controls towards the qubit count of an operation. Also, the measurement is 50/50 random so all the classically controlled gates are only present half of the time.